# how to make a regex shorter

Tags: regex

i have a rewrite rule with the following regex :

```
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$
```

which should detect the numbers located after the `-d`, `-c`and `page-` expressions from an url having this format :

```
http://localhost/tshirtshop/regional-d1/french-c1/page-2
```

i was just wondering why the regex couldn't be shorted like :

```
^.*[\-d\-c\page\-]([0-9]+)/?$ (which means beginning of the expression- any charachters repeated n times - '-d'or '-c' or 'page-'  - the expression to be catched
```

Comment: i made some tests , i added the escaping slashes like in this : ^.*[\-d\\-c\page\-]([0-9]+) but still i get errors

Comment: It al depends on what your action part is. If your target needs both numbers separately then you can't shorten it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `^.*[\-d\-c\page\-]([0-9]+)/?$` because it would capture less than you'd expect. Besides, "page" will not captured, only the individual letters, "p", "a", "g", "e". Also, `\p` is `incomplete token making the regex invalid.

Here is regex101 explanation of your "fixed" (just to see the description) shortened regex:

[image]

In htaccess rewrite rules, you cannot iterate through submatches, you have to use capture groups in order to be able to reference them in the replacement string later.

Comment: it means there is no way to write strings inside brackets i guess. No way to  write an expression with ORs between strings ?

Comment: You can, but you'll get 3 matches, and you won't be able to reference them all in the replacement string. What good is a shorter regex if you cannot use what it returns? :)

Comment: i got it :) but i'm still curious on how to do that !

Comment: I will update the answer when my main Internet connection is restored.